# Validation Not Working On Update

Tags: php, yii

No Model Validations are happening On Update. `$model->validate()` returns true always. So save happens even if wrong data

Following is change password functionality

**View**

```
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'currentpassword', array('class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required', 'value'=>'', 'maxlength'=>'40', 'pattern'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,40}', 'title'=>'Password should be 6-40 characters containing a-z and 0-9')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'currentpassword'); ?>


<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password', array('class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required', 'value'=>'', 'maxlength'=>'40', 'pattern'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,40}', 'title'=>'Password should be 6-40 characters containing a-z and 0-9')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'password'); ?>


<?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'confirmpassword', array('class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required', 'value'=>'', 'maxlength'=>'40',        'pattern'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,40}', 'title'=>'Password should be 6-40 characters containing a-z and 0-9')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'confirmpassword'); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionChangepassword()
{
        $this->layout = (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) ? '//layouts/ajax' :  '//layouts/precolumn2';


        $model = new User('changepassword');
        $data  = array();

        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {

                $model = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->User->getId());
                $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
                if ($model->save()) {
                        $message = array(
                                        'type'          =>'success',
                                        'message'       =>'Password Changed.');
                        $data['message'] = $message;
                } 
        }

        $data['model'] = $model;
        $this->render('changepassword',$data);


        }
```

**Model**

```
public function rules()
{
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
                array('name, user_type_id', 'required','on'=>'signup'),
                array('name, email', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                array('email', 'required','on'=>array('recover','signup')),
                array('email', 'exists','on'=> 'recover'),
                array('email', 'unique'),
                array('email', 'email'),
                array('user_login_count, user_like_count, user_share_count, user_view_count, user_comment_count, user_rating_count', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),

                array('password', 'length', 'max'=>100),
                array('password, confirmpassword', 'required','on'=>array('signup','resetpassword','changepassword')),
                array('confirmpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password','on'=>array('signup','resetpassword','changepassword'),'message'=>'Passwords dont match'),
                array('currentpassword', 'compareCurrentPassword','on'=>array('changepassword')),

        );
}
```

Comment: What validation is failing? The model is saving when it shouldn't?

Comment: no validations are happening. No errors thrown. Ys it should not save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your line `$model = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->User->getId());`
Looks like you need to set the scenario in there as you're creating a new user without the 'changepassword' scenario.

For example:

`$model = User::model('changepassword')->findByPk(Yii::app()->User->getId());`

Comment: how to pass scenario here